# How to convert this time format 'Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100' to UTC/GMT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, strptime

I'm converting this time format `Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100` like this

```
date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
ch = pd.read_excel(
    r'ACEOM2022-04_2022-07.xlsx',
    skiprows=[1],
    dtype{'datetime':str},
    parse_dates=["datetime"],
    date_parser=date_parser
)
```

But I would like to convert this datetime **Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100** into the same above format.
I have one more dataframe which is in UTC format.
I would like to have all the dataframes to be in UTC itself.

How can I do it in python so that all the data is in a same format? Please do provide your response.

Comment: Have another look at the parsing directive. It has to match the input *exactly*. Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100 requires `"%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z"`.

Comment: More general, `pandas.to_datetime` should be able to automatically infer the format correctly. Also, conversion to UTC is straightforward, just set keyword `utc=True` when parsing with to_datetime.

Comment: @FObersteiner  I did this approach but I get this error.      ValueError: time data 'Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

Comment: date_parser = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z")
ch1 = pd.read_excel(r'aceomDataMin0407.xlsx',skiprows=[1],dtype={'datetime':str},parse_dates=["datetime"],date_parser=date_parser,utc=True)                                                 I get this error read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'utc'   @FObersteiner

Comment: There still is a comma after %a that I don't see in you input. Did you try without?

Comment: yea I tried., this is the error.           time data 'Fri Apr 01 2022 00:01:00 GMT+0100' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z'

Comment: hm could be a locale issue, or "GMT" is not accepted by %Z. I've added a small example what you could do instead.